# single sign on iis 7.5 multiple application pools

Tags: iis-7.5, single-sign-on, webdav, application-pool

I have a webapp in two parts (website and webdav part).
Both are running in a seperate application pool in IIS 7.5 due a different framework.

I want to use single sign on for both parts. For the first part (website) its running fine but for the webdav part single sign on doesn't work with a windows 7 client.
When I try with application users (no single sign on), everything works fine for both parts.

Both application pools are running with the same service account.

I searched on the internet for a solution, but didn't find anything that worked. Does someone know how that I can solve this problem or got a manual to configure this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SingleSignon.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/aspnetsinglesignon.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972971.aspx